# HTML forms with HTML content as shows 404 error when form submission

Tags: php, html, webforms, submit

I am working with a php web site and hosted in to online server. Recently client moved this to another server. We have set of forms in admin side. I am facing issue that when ever i am submitting forms having html contents it shows 404 error always. Forms submit with no html contents (pure data) it works well.
This issue i am facing when client changed the server. I am not using any wysiag editor now. With editor and with out editor same issue exists.

```
 Forbidden
 You don't have permission to access /adminpanel/products.php on this server.

 Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an    ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Please any one suggest any server setting may cause this issue? Any help will be appreciated?

Comment: a tree view of the file structure would help us

Comment: There isn't really much to go off here... most answers will be guess work. Can you provide the HTML of the form and what a typical form submission would contain?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a path problem note that /adminpanel/ is from the domain root of the server, like www.test.com/adminpanel/file.php, instead ./adminpanel/ will be relative to the current file path.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a file permission problem. Check the files permission once and check the path of the file too.